# Why is one mean not significantly greater if every element is greater than the other group?

Tags: t-test, multiple-comparisons, paired-data, tukey-hsd-test

the mean of group C and every element in group C is greater than its row-wise peers. Why is the Tukey comparison giving insignificant P-values?

```
a           b           c           d
0.019655    0.000027    0.026986    0.010273
0.018503    0.002679    0.031533    0.012172
0.021613    0.009376    0.033388    0.017626
0.028061    0.018224    0.038585    0.025183
0.040254    0.028255    0.044642    0.033005
0.044892    0.037935    0.055145    0.039558
0.047499    0.045925    0.056831    0.044021
0.048645    0.05165     0.058121    0.046342
0.053408    0.054664    0.05911     0.047288
0.051236    0.055803    0.06435     0.047958
0.048835    0.056765    0.064827    0.04979
0.049589    0.059583    0.069493    0.053874
0.057951    0.065117    0.07688     0.060709
0.064743    0.073263    0.086837    0.070196
0.075771    0.083726    0.097591    0.081883
0.085686    0.095665    0.110035    0.095299
0.105165    0.109063    0.124393    0.109563
0.115649    0.12256     0.138772    0.123425
0.128784    0.134451    0.150204    0.135076
0.131186    0.142668    0.156827    0.14278
0.1401      0.145549    0.160151    0.145333
0.130204    0.14338     0.158275    0.142601
0.124327    0.137073    0.151098    0.135697
0.112829    0.128539    0.140068    0.126357
0.111751    0.120313    0.130949    0.117055
0.101029    0.114019    0.1233      0.109744
0.097771    0.110741    0.120195    0.105446
0.09431     0.110068    0.116499    0.104025
0.10275     0.110393    0.117894    0.104442
0.102043    0.111003    0.118317    0.105557
0.104393    0.111535    0.120446    0.106359
0.103994    0.112723    0.118055    0.106657
0.11113     0.115454    0.119636    0.10697
0.110566    0.118899    0.119617    0.107901
0.113057    0.121848    0.122219    0.109724
0.113574    0.123082    0.121973    0.111869
0.119251    0.122066    0.126177    0.113683
0.124329    0.120018    0.127068    0.114453


comp = df.melt()
m_comp = pairwise_tukeyhsd(endog=comp['value'],groups=comp['variable'])
print(m_comp.summary())

       Multiple Comparison of Means - Tukey HSD, FWER=0.05       
=================================================================
   group1        group2     meandiff p-adj   lower  upper  reject
-----------------------------------------------------------------
    trt_cgef         trt_ef   0.0045    0.9 -0.0193 0.0283  False
    trt_cgef   trt_momentum   0.0158 0.3125  -0.008 0.0396  False
    trt_cgef trt_one_over_n   0.0017    0.9 -0.0221 0.0255  False
      trt_ef   trt_momentum   0.0114 0.5894 -0.0124 0.0352  False
      trt_ef trt_one_over_n  -0.0027    0.9 -0.0266 0.0211  False
trt_momentum trt_one_over_n  -0.0141  0.417 -0.0379 0.0097  False
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Is pairwise comparison what is appropriate?  If so, you should use a test based on that.

Comment: @jbowman that's exactly it. Thanks for clarifying. Despite my research, Tukey compairs each entry to all other pairs simultaneously, which is not my desired outcome. I ended up using statsmodels.stats.multicomp.MultiComparison(df['value'],df['variable']).allpairtest(scipy.stats.ttest_rel, method="b")

Comment: I assume you got a very highly significant result?

Comment: "Row-wise peers" makes it sound like the data are blocked, and a completely different approach should be employed...  If they're not blocked, then the fact that you can arrange one group so that each member of it is larger than than a member of another group, doesn't imply statistical significance.

Comment: @SalMangiafico They are blocked: each row represents a different period.

Comment: @jbowman yes; the results were highly significant for e C group

Comment: Since the data are paired, Tukey HSD isn't an appropriate test.  It's not clear to me what the `MultiComparison` function does.  But you want to use something like a paired *t* test between the two groups or a post-hoc test appropriate for Friedman's test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data are arranged in complete block design.  Because the values between any two groups are paired, Tukey's HSD test isn't appropriate.  Instead you want to use something like a paired *t* test or other tests that take into account the paired nature of the data.

Using a test like Tukey's HSD or Student's *t* test, the fact that the data can be arranged so that an observation in one group is larger than its paired value in another group, doesn't imply that the difference should be significantly difference.

For example, take the integers 1 to 10 in one group and 2 to 11 in another group.  In R:

```
A = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8, 9,10)
B = c(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11)

t.test(A,B, var.equal=TRUE)

   ### Two Sample t-test
   ### 
   ### t = -0.73855, df = 18, p-value = 0.4697
```

Yet, if the values are treated as paired, the result is different. Here I have to jitter the values a bit to introduce enough variability in the paired differences for the test to run.

```
A = c(1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9,    10)
B = c(2.1, 2.9, 4.1, 4.9, 6.1, 6.9, 8.1, 8.9, 10.1, 10.9)

t.test(A,B, paired=TRUE)

   ### Paired t-test
   ### 
   ### t = -30, df = 9, p-value = 2.484e-10
```

In the case of the data given, since it is arranged in complete block design, a post-hoc test appropriate for Friedman's test may be appropriate.  Here, I'll use Conover's post-hoc test for Friedmans.  Note that a single-step adjustment is made to the *p* values.

Assemble the data.

```
Data = read.table(header=T, text="
a           b           c           d
0.019655    0.000027    0.026986    0.010273
0.018503    0.002679    0.031533    0.012172
0.021613    0.009376    0.033388    0.017626
0.028061    0.018224    0.038585    0.025183
0.040254    0.028255    0.044642    0.033005
0.044892    0.037935    0.055145    0.039558
0.047499    0.045925    0.056831    0.044021
0.048645    0.05165     0.058121    0.046342
0.053408    0.054664    0.05911     0.047288
0.051236    0.055803    0.06435     0.047958
0.048835    0.056765    0.064827    0.04979
0.049589    0.059583    0.069493    0.053874
0.057951    0.065117    0.07688     0.060709
0.064743    0.073263    0.086837    0.070196
0.075771    0.083726    0.097591    0.081883
0.085686    0.095665    0.110035    0.095299
0.105165    0.109063    0.124393    0.109563
0.115649    0.12256     0.138772    0.123425
0.128784    0.134451    0.150204    0.135076
0.131186    0.142668    0.156827    0.14278
0.1401      0.145549    0.160151    0.145333
0.130204    0.14338     0.158275    0.142601
0.124327    0.137073    0.151098    0.135697
0.112829    0.128539    0.140068    0.126357
0.111751    0.120313    0.130949    0.117055
0.101029    0.114019    0.1233      0.109744
0.097771    0.110741    0.120195    0.105446
0.09431     0.110068    0.116499    0.104025
0.10275     0.110393    0.117894    0.104442
0.102043    0.111003    0.118317    0.105557
0.104393    0.111535    0.120446    0.106359
0.103994    0.112723    0.118055    0.106657
0.11113     0.115454    0.119636    0.10697
0.110566    0.118899    0.119617    0.107901
0.113057    0.121848    0.122219    0.109724
0.113574    0.123082    0.121973    0.111869
0.119251    0.122066    0.126177    0.113683
0.124329    0.120018    0.127068    0.114453
")

Y = c(Data$a, Data$b, Data$c, Data$d)
Group = rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), 1, each=length(Data$a))
Block = factor(rep(1:length(Data$a),4))
```

Conover test for Friedman's Test.

```
if(!require(PMCMRplus)){install.packages("PMCMRplus")}

library(PMCMRplus)

Test = frdAllPairsConoverTest(y=Y, group=Group, block=Block, p.adjust.method = "single-step")

summary(Test)

   ### Pairwise comparisons using Conover's all-pairs test for a two-way balanced complete block design
   ### 
   ### P value adjustment method: single-step
   ### 
   ###            q value   Pr(>|q|)    
   ### B - A == 0   1.628 0.65768312    
   ### C - A == 0   4.133 0.01825587   *
   ### D - A == 0   5.761 0.00027048 ***
   ### C - B == 0   2.505 0.28732952    
   ### D - B == 0   4.133 0.01825587   *
   ### D - C == 0   1.628 0.65768312
```

To use a more traditional parametric approach, using appropriate contrasts after fitting a model accounting for the blocking should yield satisfactory results. Here, I'll treat the blocks as a random effect, though they could be treated as a fixed effect, with similar results.  Note that the results are quite different form those from the Friedman post-hoc.

```
if(!require(lme4)){install.packages("lme4")}
if(!require(emmeans)){install.packages("emmeans")}

Data2 = data.frame(Y, Group, Block)

library(lme4)

model = lmer(Y ~ Group + (1|Block), data=Data2)

library(emmeans)

marginal = emmeans(model, ~ Group)

pairs(marginal)

    ###  contrast estimate      SE  df t.ratio p.value
    ###  A - B    -0.00446 0.00104 111  -4.275 0.0002 
    ###  A - C    -0.01584 0.00104 111 -15.175 <.0001 
    ###  A - D    -0.00172 0.00104 111  -1.648 0.3564 
    ###  B - C    -0.01138 0.00104 111 -10.900 <.0001 
    ###  B - D     0.00274 0.00104 111   2.627 0.0477 
    ###  C - D     0.01412 0.00104 111  13.527 <.0001 
    ### 
    ### P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 4 estimates

plot(residuals(model), predict(model))

hist(residuals(model))
```